# Magento Google tag assistant showing errors

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics

Suddenly our magento started showing error in google tag assistant(
chrome extension)

```
No HTTP response detected.
Missing analytics.js script.
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: please mention your magento version.

Comment: mage version is 1910